# How I get name/id/@ in my command discord.js project

Tags: discord.js

i work on a discord.JS bot and I have a question on a command.

I want to create a !avatar command but I want to do this !avatar name/id/@.

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to get the user object for the argument of your command, so that you can take the avatar.
You need to do different things depending on the type:

- If any user has been mentioned (@user), you can assume that's the parameter, since you have no other arguments. You can get the user object with [`Message.mentions.users.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users)
- You can then try to get the user with the id that corresponds to your argument by first fetching all of the members and then using `.get`. If the argument is not an id, the result will be `undefined`
- Lastly, you can search the members you just fetched for someone whose username corresponds to the argument. If that fails, you can also try with the nicknames

Here's an example, assuming that `message` is the message with the command and `args[0]` is your argument.

```js
// Asynchronous method (no caching)
let user = message.mentions.users.first()

if (!user) message.guild.members.fetch(members => {
  user = members.get(args[0]) || // Gets it if it's an ID
    members.find(m => m.user.username.toLowerCase() == args[0].toLowerCase()) || // This is not case-sensitive
    members.find(m => m.nickname.toLowerCase() == args[0].toLowerCase()) // Nicknames come second, you can remove this line if you don't want them
})
```

```js
// Synchronous method (with caching)
let user = message.mentions.users.first() ||
  message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) ||
  message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.user.username.toLowerCase() == args[0].toLowerCase()) ||
  message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.nickname.toLowerCase() == args[0].toLowerCase())
```

Comment: So, I tested and can you send me a code just for find a user by him username like:

I want Dyno.

I do !avatar dyn or !avatar dyno

And the bot find the user "Dyno" and send his ID....

I work it harder but i didn't know how to do this